# adding background music to video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add bacground music to a video using ffmpeg and it is working fine but I want if length of video is more than the music file then music should start playing again till the video is over -

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

is there anyway to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following example:

```
ffmpeg -i ./INPUUT_VIDEO.mp4 -filter_complex "amovie=./INPUT_MUSIC.M4A:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest ./OUTPUT_VIDEO.mp4
```

you can set/change the audio bit rate by using `-b:a` flag, for more detail, take a look at [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) document.

**EDIT:**

***for replacing new audio in the video (repeat it until the end of the video):***

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i MUSIC.mp3 -c copy -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 OUTPUT.mp4
```

***replacing new audio in the video (repeat video until the end of the audio):***

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i VIDEO.mp4 -i MUSIC.mp3 -c copy -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Comment: It is giving an error with videos which are short or with does not have sound. error is --[mp3 @ 0x559681ef83c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description amovie=file.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a] matches no streams.

Comment: @Captain_Zaraki check this one: `ffmpeg -i ./video.mp4  -filter_complex "amovie=music.mp3:loop=0" -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest ./OUTPUT_VIDEO.mp4
`

Comment: @PS-PASRA thanks for helping me, but now it is giving error for long video or it is getting stuck and keep throwing this error- [mp4 @ 0x55705b18dcc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1520938, current: 65024; changing to 1520939. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

Comment: @Captain_Zaraki I edited the post, check it again...